# How to check if SSL socket gets closed (async)

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, boost-asio

I've been using boost asio for networking for some time, but never for SSL sockets. Now i'm required to use SSL sockets and they work pretty fine. But i am not able to find out when a sockets get closed (I usually did this as I did with regular sockets - checking the error value when using `boost::asio::async_read_until()` in the callback function.

Here's some relevant code snippets:

```
boost::asio::streambuf streambuf;
boost::asio::ssl::context sslctx(io_service, boost::asio::ssl::context::tlsv1);
boost::asio::ssl::stream<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket> sock(io_service, sslctx);

void DoAsyncRead()
{
    boost::asio::async_read_until(sock, streambuf, "\n", MyReadHandler);
}

void MyReadHandler(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  if (error) {
    std::cout << "Read error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
  } else {
    // ...
  }
}
```

The error condition is never true, even if I kill the server, or drop the client connection. How can I track if the connection is closed?

Comment: do you see the same behavior when using `async_read()` as you do with `async_read_until()`?

Comment: @SamMiller sadly, no. there should be no difference for error handling between these both anyway. it looks like the problem is the SSL stream. when using `tcp::socket`, the error handler works fine for eof or any other error regarding the connection loss.

Comment: are you aware of the subtle differences between `async_read` and `async_read_until`? It really depends on how your application handles the `bytes_transferred` parameter in your completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

EOS is not an error condition in most APIs. It is a sentinel value returned instead of a byte count, typically zero (Unix) or -1 (Java).

Comment: Boost.Asio works a little different compared to the UNIX API, even if it is just some kind of wrapper. The error condition must be true when `eof` or any other error, such as broken pipe etc., is received. As mentioned above, this works fine when using plain tcp sockets, but not with the SSL stream.